# How to do a sort based on more than one string

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects that I need to sort based on two sets of criteria.

```
let arr = [
  { name: "GMC", postalCode: "23456" },
  { name: "Tesla", postalCode: "12345" },
  { name: "GMC", postalCode: "12345" }
];
```

I need to sort based on name first, and then postalCode second. All the names need to be alphabetical, and in that alphabetical sort, I need to sort any of them with the same name by postalCode. So the result needs to be.

```
[
  { name: "GMC", postalCode: "12345" }
  { name: "GMC", postalCode: "23456" },
  { name: "Tesla", postalCode: "12345" },
];
```

I feel like this should be really simple, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: `I don't know what I'm doing wrong.`  Can you show us what you're doing?  We can help.

Comment: Why did you un-accept my answer- do you need additional help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a [custom sort function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like this. Note the pluses in front of the references to the postalCodes- it's a cast to a number so that we do a numeric comparison instead of a string comparison.

```
arr.sort((a, b) => {
  if (a.name > b.name) return -1;
  if (a.name < b.name) return 1;
  if (a.name == b.name) {
    if ((+a.postalCode) > (+b.postalCode)) return -1;
    if ((+a.postalCode) < (+b.postalCode)) return 1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to do this would be to sort by the concatenated value of the two fields. This would look like this:

```
const data = [
    { name: "GMC", postalCode: "12345" },
    { name: "GMC", postalCode: "23456" },
    { name: "Tesla", postalCode: "12345" },
];

data.sort((a, b) => (a.name + a.postalCode).localeCompare(b.name + b.postalCode));
```

Comment: Imagine a name like "GMC1"- you could fix this with a separator, but even then what if the name contains that separator?

Comment: I like this solution, and agree, a delimiter should be added, though it isn't strictly necessary.  I doubt a name field will end with a number, or a postal code starting with a letter.

Comment: This is a great solution, but wouldn't work in my case because of the potential for odd characters to be in both the name and postalCode fields. This application, unfortunately, has some ugly ugly data in places.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use a custom [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) callback function comparing one value to another returning:

- `1` if the first value is to be sorted before the second
- `-1` if the second item is to be sorted before the first
- `0` if they are both equal and sorting is left to the internals.

---

```
[4,8,2].sort((a,b)=>{
  if(a>b){ 
    return 1;
  } else if(a<b){
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
});
```

To do it for multiple criteria simply do the next criteria check in the instances where you would regularly return `0` (when the previous criteria values matched). Repeat as needed for the number of criteria you need to check against.

```
[{a:1,b:3},{a:2,b:4},{a:1,b:1}].sort((first,second)={
  if(first.a > second.a){
    return 1;
  } else if(first.a < first.b){
    return -1;
  }
  //instead of returning 0 do the next criteria check
  if(first.b > second.b){
    return 1;
  } else if(first.b < second.b){
    return -1;
  }
  //return 0 since every criteria matched (or add another criteria check)
  return 0;
});
```

Once you get it working you can then go back and make optimizations like making it so you don't repeat blocks of code.